# Git cancel a revert

Tags: git, version-control

In git let say I commit A and B

```
A---[B]
```

But then I revert with

```
git revert HEAD
```

So I am there now:

```
[A]---B
```

How do I cancel my revert so that I can go back to B?

Comment: I am not sure how the term "revert" is used in Git means, but in general, reverting means to overwrite any local changes. So only an undelete tool could help at all, but there are little chances.

Comment: @Andreas: In Git, a "revert" is a *new* commit that reverses the application of some earlier commit.

Comment: Your picture is inaccurate. After the revert, you have `A---B---!B`, where `!B` is the commit reverting `B`. Greg's two answers, respectively, create a commit `!!B` reverting `!B` or return you to `B`.

Comment: "git reset --hard REF", replace "REF" with the reference or SHA you want to get back to. http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You have two general choices:

- Revert the revert commit (creating a second revert commit that takes you back to the original)
- Throw away the revert commit with

> git reset --hard HEAD^

The second option is only appropriate if you have *not* pushed your changes anywhere else. In fact, if you haven't pushed your first revert commit anywhere yet, you can simply use

> git reset --hard

to roll back without creating any revert commits at all.

Comment: Don't do the reset --hard just like I did, I lost all foreign files in my repo!

Comment: Maybe suggest a `git stash` first.

Answer (score 24):

If you haven't done it completely, i.e., in `gitbash` you see something like:

```
Username@Host MINGW64 /d/code/your-project (feature|REVERTING)
```

then you can use `git revert --abort` to abort.

If you have done it.. just don't reset, the changes are still there. Use `git reset` to change the state. Instead of `--hard`, you can also use `--soft`(keep all the changes).

```
git reset --soft HEAD^ // discard the last commit, keeping all the changes after that
```

Also, if you want to revert more than 1 commits:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3 // discart last 3 commits. Don't know if it works for commits of others.
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the --abort option.

Comment: I have to do a `git revert --abort` twice with `git reset --hard` in between, since the first one reported failure.

Comment: For this case your answer is more fast, security and documental. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you create a new `commit` which `reverts another commit` you can treat it like a normal commit.

So basically you have many choices, such as

> - `git rebase -i` (remove the revert commit)
> - `git reset --hard <commitID>` (reset to the commit before the revert, **you'll lose all local changes**)
> - `git reset --soft <commitID>` (same as above but keeps local changes)
> - technically you can use `git revert <commitId>` to revert your revert

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is "cherry-pick" original commit and push again.